# Why PYTHONPATH need to be exported?

Tags: python, shell, environment-variables, pythonpath

I am getting some module not found excepiton when setting PYTHONPATH and *then* executing some py script :

```
$ PYTHONPATH=somepath/a/b
$ python myscript.py

Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: _run_module_as_main)
No module named 'c'
```

but if I export PYTHONPATH, everything works fine

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=somepath/a/b
$ python myscript.py

==>ok
```

It is also working when I am inlining the PYTHONPATH assignation :

```
$ PYTHONPATH=somepath/a/b python myscript.py

==>ok
```

Why do we have this behavior ?

Comment: How could the Python interpreter know what its value was if it wasn't exported? Only variables _exported to the environment_ are copied to subprocesses.

Comment: (or, more accurately: only values stored in the environment block survive the `execve()` operation when a process replaces its memory image with that contained in a different executable file; thus, in the `fork()`+`execve()` two-step of creating a subprocess and running a different program in it, the place where only environment variables survive is that second step).

Answer (score 2):

I'm amazed this doesn't seem to be a duplicate, but:

"Why ...?" -- because you're using a traditional (Bourne/Korn-family) shell on Unix or a Unix-alike such as WSL, although you don't identify which in your Q. This is the type of shell required by POSIX, and often described as such. Other Unixy shells like csh-family or fish are different and so are Windows command processors, although those do have *some* way to set environment variables.

**In a POSIX shell, each variable has an attribute to select whether it is 'exported', that is, passed as an *environment variable*** (an OS feature) when running as a child process a program such as python (or a script).

Any of the following commands or sequences (possibly separated by other unrelated commands) sets a variable as 'exported':

```
export foo=bar
export foo; foo=bar
foo=bar; export foo
typeset -x foo=bar
typeset -x foo; foo=bar
foo=bar; typeset -x foo
# in many Bourne/Korn shells declare is another name for typeset
```

*IF* the shell option `-a` is set, a simple assignment `foo=bar` also sets the export attribute.

These settings are 'permanent'; the exported variables are passed to all programs (and scripts) run subsequently, unless and until explicitly unset or changed or the shell exits.

In addition, a 'word' `foo=bar` at the beginning of a simple-command, prior to the word which specifies the program to be run, adds or replaces an environment variable for that command/process *only* -- unless the command is shell builtin, in which case the POSIX behavior is unspecified and actual shells may vary.

**But an assignment `foo=bar` by itself -- not as a prefix to a simple-command and not preceded or followed by setting the export attribute and without option `-a` in effect -- only sets a *shell* variable which is NOT 'exported' so it is not passed to or seen by a child process such as python.**

Comment: I wouldn't describe this as shell-specific. Same difference between values stored in the environment vs elsewhere in process-local memory exists in every language; focusing too closely on shell details obscures that.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: not Windows CMD, there _all_ vars are envvars.

Comment: Eh. It's true at the C layer, so anything on top of that layer that enforces a "all variables are environment variables" policy is creating new restrictions for its own purposes. And if Windows environment variables are implemented similarly to UNIX ones, that's a substantial restriction -- means a limit on the total memory used by all defined variables, means command line arguments count against that same limit, &c.